# Z / 6Z being a set of well dedfined equivalence classes, and a congruent to b(mod 6)

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations

why is this = [0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]

and how would I define f Z/6Z - Z/6Z by f([a]) = ([2a]). I have the proof but I don't understand it.

Proof: Assume [a1] = [a2] in Z/6Z. then a1 congruent to a2(mod 6), so 6| a1 - a2. Thus, 6 | 2(a1 -a2) **don't know why we use a 2 to multiply it all** by property of divisibility, hence 6 | 2a1 - 2a2. But then 2a1 congruent to 2a2(mod 6) so by definition 2a1 =2a2 and finally f([a1]) = f([a2]).

Not sure how that conclusion is reached or what happened exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal was to prove that $f$ is a *well defined* function, i.e. it assigns exactly *one* value to any element of its domain.

$\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ contains **six** elements. Note that $[6]=[0]$ therein (and $[7]=[1]$ and $[8]=[2]$ and $[12]=[0]$ again, and $[-1]=[5]$, and so on..).

So, we take *one* element of this quotient set, which is one *equivalence class*. But we can only work by its *representatives*, the integers. So it starts with assuming that this class is represented by different integers $a_1$ and $a_2$. Then, we write the definition, multiply by $2$ because we want to prove that $f=[x]\mapsto[2x]$ is well defined, and arrive to
$[2a_1]=[2a_2]$, which shows that the value of $f([x])$ is indeed *independent* of the choice of representative $x$ of the equivalence class.

Comment: Side note: It is not unusial in certain areas of mathematics to have a function $f$ and at the same time some equivalence relation $\sim$ on the same domain (the integers in this example). A commonly asked question is then: If we take an element from some equivalence class and use the function on that element, which equivalence class do we end up in? And does it matter, within one equivalence class, which element we feed into $f$? This is what you're asked to figure out.